# Why does javascript form validation is not working in cpanel but worked perfectly in wamp server?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      function Validate()
{
     if (document.registration_form.fname.value == '') 
    {
        alert('Please fill in your fname!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="registration_form" form action="reginsert_interest.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return Validate();">
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0"  bgcolor="#CCCCFF">
 <tr><font size="5">Registration</font></tr>
 <tr>
    <td width="150" bgcolor="#9999FF"><strong><font size="4">First Name:</font></strong></td>
          <td width="150"bgcolor="#9999FF"><font size="3"><input name="fname" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30"></font></td></tr>
</table>
 
 
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

I was trying an example to test the form validation,but it does not work in cpanel.

Comment: any errors in console??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju There have no errors, as the form fields are passed to the next page and also to the database successfully.

Comment: I found one thing that,this validation works in firefox but not in chrome.I have collation in my database field at utf8_swedish_ci .

Comment: Why don't u use jQuery for this??